# vb.net before date is less than datetime now

Tags: vb.net, datetime, date

the last date was saved on database is:
 6/13/2012 12:27:30 PM

In my DateTime Now is:
6/13/2012 01:27:57 AM

but, when I execute this function, it always say:
"Date has been manually modified, Please Set to Valid DateTime"

But, DateTime Now is NOT lessthan the Date from my Database.  What's wrong?

This is the code, please correct it,

```
Private lastdate As DateTime
Private Sub GetDBdate()
...
    Dim ss As String
    Dim sc As New SQLiteCommand
    ss = "select dtime from dincome order by dtime desc limit 1"
    sc = New SQLiteCommand(ss, mycon)
    lastdate = CDate(sc.ExecuteScalar)
End Sub



    Private Function CheckValidDate() As Boolean
    Dim dtnow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    If dtnow < lastdate Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
    End Function




    Private Sub Button_Click
    If Not CheckValidDate() Then
    label1.Text = "Date has been manually modified, Please Set to Valid DateTime"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ...
    ...
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: But 01:27 AM (Now) is less than 12:27 PM (LastDate) and therefore invalid.

Comment: @Nico Schertler, yeah your right, I didn't see that, but how come my database has a date of 6/13/2012 while or when the date is 6/12/2012 PM, I'll watch like Bryan Beecham said. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your time is about one hour off.  Have you checked your time zone settings? This has caused me issue in the past.

Comment: actually my database datetime saved like this: 2012-06-13 12:27:30 , as you noticed there is no AM/PM tag, so when I compared it to the time Now that is AM, then it say's Now is less than, because in the database it was read PM, but was AM when saved and it was not tag as AM or PM in the database.  I think there's something wrong with my datetime procedure saving.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

it was a 24hour issue I think, yesterday I removed the tt from

Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

supposed to be:

Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")

thanks both